# Only the first if is being evaluated in JSRender

Tags: jquery, jsrender

I have an object that I am rendering in JSRender. Almost everything works except for the evaluation of a nested object I have.

```json
"traits": {
  "admin": true,
  "editor": true,
  "writer": true
}
```

It is part of a larger object that I am sending to the template.

I have been trying to get JSRender to display an icon next to a name based on the traits.

```html
{{if traits.admin}}
  <div class="icon iconadmin"></div>
{{/if}}
{{if traits.editor}}
  <div class="icon iconeditor"></div>
{{/if}}
{{if traits.writer}}
  <div class='icon iconwriter'></div>
{{/if}}
```

I have tried using an `{{if}} {{else }}` structure as well as a `{{for}}` loop but in each case the template only renders the first icon the user has in their traits object.

If I switch the code around it will successfully display, for instance, the editor icon if I move the test for editor to be evaluated first.

Is the problem that I am using an object?

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally wrong with that code.  If you put those three `<div>` tags in the template without any ifs at all, do you see all three icons?

Comment: I'll give that a try tomorrow

Comment: So if I pull the divs out of the conditionals they all appear but inside the conditional block only the first one appears.

Comment: It also doesn't work if I change the code to use a key/value pair that is outside of the object `traits`

Answer (score 0):

I can get the code to work using {{props}}

```
{{props traits}}
 {{if prop}}
    <div class="icon icon{{>key}}"></div>
  {{/if}}
{{/props}}
```

At that point it will iterate over the properties in the `traits` key and then evaluate them.

I am going to enter this as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It works correctly for me:

https://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/4cL5a0qv/

If I set

```
"admin": false,
"editor":true,
"writer": true
```

Then this template:

```
{{if traits.admin}}
  <div>ADMIN</div>
{{else traits.editor}}
  <div>EDITOR</div>
{{else traits.writer}}
  <div>WRITER</div>
{{/if}}


{{if traits.admin}}
  <div>ADMIN2</div>
{{/if}}
{{if traits.editor}}
  <div>EDITOR2</div>
{{/if}}
{{if traits.writer}}
  <div>WRITER2</div>
{{/if}}
```

outputs:

```
EDITOR
EDITOR2
WRITER2
```

`{{if}}...{{else}}...` will output a block only for the first true expression.

`{{if}}...{{/if}}` will output each time the expression is true

If it doesn't work for you can you post a jsfiddle...? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't do them all though. If I set all the values to true in your fiddle I get the following output

ADMIN
ADMIN2
EDITOR2
WRITER2

So it Skips Editor1 and Writer1

Comment: That is what it is supposed to do. if a else b else c will output just the first true value.  https://www.jsviews.com/#iftag: Multiple alternative conditional blocks: – Render the first {{if}} or {{else}} block for which the expression is true...

Comment: In your case, you don't want that - so just use the three {{if}}...{{/if}} blocks, without {{else}} - as in the second part of my jsfiddle template.

Comment: I will try to set up a fiddle to do a test case but I thought that part of the debate that was had on github regarding the {{ifelse}} tag was that it wasn't required. I guess I just didn't understand the docs or the discussion.

Comment: Well I don't know what the heck is going on now but I went back and removed the {{props}} code and added the consecutive conditionals and it runs.

The template used some CSS code that I didn't include in the example here and it may have been causing display issues. I was certain that I checked that though.

Sorry for the bother. On the plus side I am actually happier with the `{{props}}` code I am using as a 'solution'.

On to integrating it with views.